# Simple modal slide-in with text-Is it necessary to use jQuery?

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, slide

I need to simply create a 'popin' or 'slide-in' box containing text( a hidden div) over my existing application. Being modal is optional but not a requirement. A simple close button on the box will close(animate it) off the page.

Is jQuery necessary to accomplish this?

Comment: necessary != simplest. what is your question exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery is not necessary to do anything. After all, you can just write your own Javascript that does whatever jQuery would do. I think for a box like you describe, it wouldn't even be that difficult.

jQuery is simply a tool that makes certain Web page interactions easier to program. Like any tool, you need to know when to use it or not. If you're not already using jQuery on your site, then adding it for one dialog is not necessarily prudent. On the other hand, if you're already using it, why not use it once more?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend taking a look at th jqueryUI components here is a link for Jhueryui dialog it sounds like what you are looking for.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is a modal box. Jquery has their own modal function, which you can check out: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

I believe jquery would be easy. There are other plugins out there. You can also check out SimpleModal by Eric Martin : http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/ His plugin has a lot of cool features too

It'll be easy to integrate his plugin and you can change your content to your liking.